Error with 2sxc apps on site since this morning
We've got a site running for some years, with 2sxc apps (content and other apps, like news, and some custom stuff). Since this morning we got this error saying:
"
Error: System.Exception: Data is missing. This is common when a site is copied but the content / apps hav not been imported yet. - check 2sxc.org/help?tag=export-import - Zone/App: 7/-100;App NameId: ; ContetnBlock Guid:
"
There has been no import or export, no new site created.
Nobody here says they did anything to the site.
When I check the portals folder, all files seem to be there. When I check some of the 2sxc tables, they seem to have records in them.
In the meantime I have restored a backup for our customer, but that is not a real solution of course. I mean if this happens once, it can happen again.
So I am wondering what could be causing this. And if there is something we can do to restore the apps. The rest of the site/dnn is all working fine, only the 2sxc apps give this error.

Please provide more info about versions etc. Did you also try restarting before a restore? it sounds like a caching issue.

Yes, we've tried a lot of things. REstarting, clearing the cache, etc. So strange issue...
Like I said I installed a backup on another instance in Azure. The old site is still up under a test domain if you're interested to take a look. It is a DNN 9.10.2 with a bit older version of 2sxc - 13.12

if it's such an old version we won't look into it. Changes are huge, that an update would fix it. Could you try that?

Sorry this is out of sequence, but... is the same, a related, or a more detailed error being throw in /Portals/_default/logs/2024.06.nn.log.resources?

Just tried updating to 2sxc 17.9 but that did not do much. It actually gave me the install apps dialogue you get when you install 2sxc for the first time. So it looks like it thinks no apps are installed whatsoever.

Given everything you've provided and including the comments, it seems very likely getting both DNN and 2sxc upgraded to the latest versions should fix this permanently.
If its still happening after the upgrades, please post a screenshot of the error so we have better context on the error. I am assuming its in the Event Log, but if not, that might add a clue or two.

My first sentence seems to say what you are asking. Upgrading is the solution. Since, from experience, its possible it may not work, I provided suggestions on the next steps and what details (logs) people might find useful to see. So, though I generally agree with and always strive to do as your comment suggests, I felt this needed a more pragmatic approach. a) here is the likely solution, b) if not, we could use more info (and where to find it).

I am assuming you know things above my pay grade and experience. I am just trying to help someone. I went ahead and moved my the question to so it is now a comment on the original question.

That seems very appropriate, thanks. What remains is practically the "If ... then ..." I had in mind. ;-) Concerning the pay grade, that is .... not really what this is about. Let me just share the insight with you, that your post triggered something and ended up in a list of posts that have a higher risk than usual to be flagged as "not an answer". Which yours (apart from the now removed part) does not deserve. If you wanted to hint that I came over patronising or something I could somewhat understand. But I hope you see the attempt to actually help you.

Thanks for the extra info! I very much appreciate it - Jeremy
